# Is it possible to use Nexus to proxy a private npmjs org?

Tags: npm, nexus

I have a private npmjs.com org. For certain builds in certain environments, I cannot connect to it, but I *can* connect to a Nexus repository.

I was wondering whether it is possible to set up an NPM proxy with NPM credentials for a private org. Searching the documentation and online hasn't revealed how to do this yet (as it is a weird use case, if you have Nexus why bother with a private npmjs org, just use Nexus!) most examples are for setting up  your own private repository.

Any help would be much appreciated! I know it is an odd use case but I am looking for an interim solution to a larger problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not likely to work until this is fixed: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12456

Comment: Much appreciated @rseddon, that does seem to confirm it is not supported. Thanks!